# Pass a session variable in Footable from Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use session variable in Footable.

I call a jquery function "getjsonfile()" which will look in my PHP file "getjson.php"  my session variable.

So, If I do an Alert in my "getjsonfile()" function, I get without problem the value of the session variable.

But I can't pass this value in my "jsonfile" variable for use in Footable.

What is wrong with my code ? I hope I have done enough detail. Thanks !!!

```
/*=== My getjson.php File ===*/
<?php
// $_SESSION file_content_json can be either  "content.json" OR "admin.content.json"
session_start();
$file_content_json = $_SESSION['file_content_json'];
die(json_encode(array('file_content_json' => $file_content_json)));
?>



/*=== My function ===*/
function getjsonfile() {
      $.ajax({
      url: 'getjson.php',
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
            //alert("file="+data.file_content_json);
            return data.file_content_json;
            },
      });               
};


/*=== My main Footable ===*/
jQuery(function($) {
var jsonfile = getjsonfile();
    
    var $modal = $('#editor-modal'),
        $editor = $('#editor'),
        $editorTitle = $('#editor-title'),

        ft = FooTable.init('#editing-data', {
            columns: $.get("content/"+jsonfile), /* Here, I need my value (session variable) */
            editing: {
                enabled: true,
                addRow: function() {
                    /*.... following stuff ...*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hassan Azzi, I can't seem to get your proposal to work completely.

getjsonfile() works well, and the value is displayed correctly with // test.

But after that, jsonfile.file_content_json remains recognized.

Nevertheless, many thanks for your answer which encouraged me to finally find a solution to my example.

Here is my solution:

```
/*=== My getjson.php File ===*/
<?php
// $_SESSION file_content_json can be either  "content.json" OR "admin.content.json"
session_start();
$file_content_json = $_SESSION['file_content_json'];
die(json_encode(array('file_content_json' => $file_content_json)));
?>

/*=== My function ===*/
function getjsonfile() {
    var result = JSON.parse($.ajax({
        url: 'getjson.php',
        async: false
    }).responseText);
    return result.file_content_json;
}

/*=== My main Footable ===*/
jQuery(function($) {
var jsonfile = getjsonfile();
        //..
        ft = FooTable.init('#editing-data', {
            columns: $.get("content/"+jsonfile),
            editing: {
                enabled: true,
                addRow: function() {
                    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why did you choose this route to share information. anyway, you could use the built-in fetch() to return the data with async await.

**getjson.php**

```php
<?php
  session_start();
    
  $_SESSION['file_content_json'] = "Your session content";
    
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  exit(json_encode([
    'file_content_json' => $_SESSION['file_content_json']
  ]));

?>
```

**JS file**

```js
async function getjsonfile() {
  const response = await fetch('getjson.php');
  return response.json();
}

// test
(async function() {
  var content = await getjsonfile();
  console.log(content.file_content_json);
})();

// in your case (use async function)
jQuery(async function($) {
  var jsonfile = await getjsonfile();
    
  //..
  ft = FooTable.init('#editing-data', {
    columns: jsonfile.file_content_json,
    editing: {
      enabled: true,
      addRow: function() {
        //...
      }
    }
  }
});
```